# Second Dropdown concern, Php, Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, ajax

This code comes from a guide I've seen in YouTube.

I'm trying to populate the second dropdown based on the choices on the first dropdown, in my test page its working, however when I tried to attach it to my main page, the second dropdown is not turning into a dropdown.

I've tried to re-code it, but still the problem persist.

This is for the AJAX

```
 <?php
    include('db.php');
    if($_POST['id']){
        $id=$_POST['id'];
        if($id==0){
            echo "<option value='0'>Select Type</option>";
            }else{
                $sql = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM `ConcernType` WHERE Concern_Id='$id'");
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
                    echo '<option value="'.$row['ConcernType_id'].'">'.$row['ConcernType_name'].'</option>';

                    }
                }
            }
    ?>
```

This is for the index.php

```
    <label>Concern Category :</label><select name="concerncategory" class="concerncategory">
    <option value="0">Select Category</option>
    <?php
    include('db.php');
    $sql = mysqli_query($con,"select * from ConcernCategory");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql))
    {
    echo '<option value="'.$row['Concern_Id'].'">'.$row['ConcernCategory_name'].'</option>';
    } ?>
    </select><br/><br/>
    <label>Concern Type :</label><select name="concerntype" class="concerntype">
    <option value="0">Select Type</option>
    </select>
    <br /><br />

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
    $(".concerncategory").change(function()
    {
    var Concern_Id=$(this).val();
    var post_id = 'id='+ Concern_Id;
    $.ajax ({
    type: "POST", url: "ajax.php", data: post_id, cache: false,
    success: function(Type) {
    $(".concerntype").html(Type);
    } }); }); });
    </script>
```

Here are some screenshots.

https://ibb.co/2NTTdG8

https://ibb.co/fFXBzFS

Comment: Please be aware that your code is **vulnerable** to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). **Never** use `$_POST` (or equivalent variables) directly in SQL statements! You should use [**prepared statements**](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead, binding to variables. Also ensure the user only has the [**required privileges**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege). You can refer to [**this post**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174) for further information on how to prevent SQL injection in PHP :)

Comment: what is result of your ajax call?

Comment: thank you for the heads up @ObsidianAge . I will recode the system soon.

Comment: please see image; https://ibb.co/syc0fZJ @daremachine

Comment: @pjustindaryll I mean in console. Broken rendered result not help.

Comment: you have to append your ajax response code to your select box. Use $(".concerntype").append(Type) instead of $(".concerntype").html(Type).